# How to set views in BottomSheetDialog for different state STATE_EXPANDED and STATE_COLLAPSED?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-motionlayout, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have single layout with title, 3 items and button. I need to set just title, 1 item and button if state is STATE_COLLAPSED and all views fo STATE_EXPANDED. How I must to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set View.Visibile when `bottomsheet`is expanded and View.GONE when `bottomsheet`is callpsed.
More code would be nice.

use `bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback()`and override the `onStateChanged` method.

States of bottomsheetbehavior has state methods of the bottomsheetdialog